# Informix to MySQL Conversion

Tags: mysql, informix

We have a old Informix Database at my place of employment and are looking for a solid solution for migrating all of the data from Informix to MySQL.

Does anyone have knowledge of a proven solution for this migration?

Answer (score 3):

Is the schema too large or too complex to edit manually?
Informix and MySQL syntax is very similar and you should be able to clean the sql statements just using some sed scripts.

There are many tools available and a MySQL resource discussing various options [can be found here](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/migration-software.html), but I would be inclined to just dump the dbschema, try and load it into MySQL and fix the bits that break.

Answer (score 1):

Just for Information, if the problem is the cost with Informix license upgrade, you can use the new Informix Innovator-C v11.50 , what is *Free for production*.

Supports 1 socket CPU (or 4 cores),
No sessions/user limits,
2 GB memory,
no database size limit,
support 2 nodes in High Availability for free,
support 2 nodes in Enterprise Replication for free,
Optional official IBM support contract... if need...

Check the IBM site for more information: www.ibm.com/informix

Comment: Also: www.informix.com (which redirects to the IBM site).  The URL editor removed the www. when that was prefixed with 'http://'; that is frustrating because informix.com does not work the same as www.informix.com does.